# Lower bound on tail probability for maximum of independent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

I'm having difficulty solving a problem from van der Vaart & Wellner (1996). Problem 2.3.2 on page 120 asks the reader to prove:

For independent random variables $\xi_1, \ldots, \xi_n$,

$$
P\left(\max_i |\xi_i| >x\right) \ge \frac{\sum_i P(|\xi_i|>x)}{1 + \sum_i P(|\xi_i|>x)}.
$$

There is a hint: For $x\ge 0$, one has $1-x\le \exp(-x)$ and $1-e^{-x}\ge x/(1+x)$.

I'm not sure how to start with proving this statement. Clearly the form $x/(1+x)$ in the hint is the same as the form on the rhs of the inequality, however I'm not sure how to get the $1-e^{-x}$ in there.

Any hints / suggestions as to how to attack this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean "Problem 2.3.$\mathbf{\color{red}2}$" ?

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin Yes, thanks. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$
\begin{align*}
P\left(\max_i |\xi_i| >x\right)&=1-P\left(\max_i |\xi_i| \leq x\right)\\
&=1-\prod_{i=1}^n(1-P(|\xi_i|> x))\tag{0}\\
&\ge1-\prod_{i=1}^n\exp(-P(|\xi_i|> x))\tag{1}\\
&=1-\exp\left(-\sum_{i=1}^nP(|\xi_i|>x)\right)\\
&\geq \frac{\sum_i P(|\xi_i|>x)}{1 + \sum_i P(|\xi_i|>x)}\tag{2}
\end{align*}
$$
where in $(0)$ we used the independence of the $\xi_i$, in $(1)$ we use the fact that $1-x\leq e^{-x} $ for $x\geq 0$ and in $(2)$ we use the fact that $1-e^{-x}\geq x/(1+x)$ for $x\geq 0$.